# How to configure a prometheus installation of openshift to include the labels of node role in the exporter?

Tags: prometheus, openshift

We want to alert based on cpu requests only on worker nodes

namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{kubernetes_node_role=~"worker"}

gives no datapoints and

```
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum
```

```
Element Value
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{namespace="aaaaa-dev"}   2.4
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{namespace="dev-xxxxx"}   0.8600000000000001
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{namespace="dev-yyyyy"}   1.2100000000000006
namespace_cpu:kube_pod_container_resource_requests:sum{namespace="dev-zzzzz"}   0.6
```

I have reviewed this documentation without success
[1] https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/prometheus_cluster_monitoring.html
[2] https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/